# Read .csv file and save its values in a list of arrays

Tags: php, csv

I am new at php programming but I have been stuck with this code for some time.
I would like to read a .csv file line by line and then save its values in a list of arrays.

```
$file = fopen('Sub-Companies.csv', 'r');    
while (($line =
fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) { 
print_r($line);
list($customer_id[],$company_name[],$department[],$employee[],$country[],$zipcode[],$address[],$city[],
$smth1[], $smth2[], $phone_no1[],$phone_no2[],$email[],$website[],
$customer_no[],$problem1[],$problem2[]) = explode(";",$line);  }
fclose($file); var_dump($customer_id);
```

The problem is that, although it is read correctly the file, then the explode is not working and the arrays appear to be null.

One thing that I am considering is that some arrays have more ";" than others, so that might be a problem, that is why I have the arrays $problem1 and $problem2, in order to store the values of this arrays.

Any help would be great!

Comment: 1.) Please post an example of your CSV file. 2.) I've never seen such a code using `list()` with more than 10 parameters!!

Comment: for example I have this entry: 601C6E90-DC11-41B1-B121-30859C532046;;NULL;NULL;DE;19073;NULL;WittenfÃ¶rden;NULL;NULL;0004004;839828298;email@address.de;NULL;ibd21 Do you think is it a problem that I have so many parameters?

Comment: If it helps I have also tried this code: `$string1 = "his; is a; nw;house"; 
$testarray = explode(";",$string); 
print_r($testarray); 
` which works but when I use this one `$testarray = explode(";",$line);  
print_r($testarray);` it doesn't.

Comment: It's rather a problem of reading the code ;) You're using `fgetcsv()` the wrong way! Try this script: http://pastebin.com/1P70pxc0

Comment: Well, I did it as you suggested and when I print it gives me NULL.

Comment: What do you print? The code should already output all data (as single arrays for each line).

Comment: First of all I used `$handle = fopen('Sub-Companies', 'r'); 

while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {

var_dump($line);` to see the result of the code and it is printed NULL

Comment: Isn't it `Sub-Companies.**csv**`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! Okay, now each line is split into strings. What I want to do is to store the first value of each line into an array1, the second value of each line into an array2 etc. Can that happen with this code? I used `list( $customer_id[],
  $company_name[],
  $department[] etc) = $line ` but it doesn't seem to work when I try to print `var_dump($customer_id);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19600/discussion-between-comfreek-and-dimitra-micha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `fgetcsv()` in the wrong way.

We've come to this solution while [chatting here on StackOverflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19600/discussion-between-comfreek-and-dimitra-micha).

```
<?php
// Create file data.csv with your data
$handle = fopen('Sub-Companies.csv', 'r');

$customer_id = array();
$xyz_array = array();
// ...

// Better use a specified length (second parameter) instead of 0
// It slows down the whole process of reading the data!
while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ';')) !== FALSE) {
  $customer_id[] = $line[0];
    $xyz_array[] = $line[1];
}
```